# Posicionar un botón flotante

Tags: javascript, html, html5, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 5, Materialize tengo un botón flotante el cual necesito que se vea en la parte superior derecha de la vista pero me aparece en la parte inferior derecha.

Estoy trabajando con materialize [Horizontal FAB](http://materializecss.com/buttons.html) Horizontal FAB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese botón de lápiz debo ponerlo en la parte de arriba donde indica la flecha amarilla. Este es mi código:

```
<body>
<div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<table id="proveedores" class="table table-hover display" >
    <thead style="background-color:#337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
        <tr>
            <td>ProveedorId</td>
            <td>Razón Social</td>
            <td>Número documento</td>
            <td>Dirección</td>
            <td>Teléfono</td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in ViewBag.ListarProveedor)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row.ProveedorId</td>
                <td>@row.RazonSocial</td>
                <td>@row.NumeroDocumento</td>
                <td>@row.Direccion</td>
                <td>@row.Telefono</td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El fixed-action-btn está hecho para que siempre esté pegado a la esquina inferior derecha de la página es por eso que tiene la propiedad `position: fixed;` , si deseas alterar esto puedes envolverlo en otra etiqueta con `position: relative;` y al botón ponerlo como `position: absolute;` y esta etiqueta colocarla en donde quieras colocar el botón, por ejemplo:

En el HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="action-btn-wrapper">
                <div class="fixed-action-btn my-custom-btn horizontal">
                    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
                        <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">playlist_add</i></a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">play_for_work</i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Proveedor</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

y en tu CSS:

```
.action-btn-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.fixed-action-btn.my-custom-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 23px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

OJO: en la clase de tu botón fixed-action-btn le añado la clase my-custom-btn para no alterar el estilo del botón original.

Te dejo la liga de un CodePen para que lo veas [aquí](http://codepen.io/lurias_b/pen/vgMEyV?editors=1100#0).

#### Update:

Si quieres modificar aún más el posicionamiento del botón puedes modificar los valores del `top` y `right` para que quede exactamente donde tu quieres. Un buen recurso para  entender el posicionamiento de los elementos es la página de [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) aunque un curso general de CSS te ayudaría muy bien a entenderlo. Ej. [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html-css). Saludos!

Comment: Hola, has creado un css? solo tengo el css de materialize

Comment: Bernardo, como te distes cuenta de las modificaciones que había que hacerse, hay algún link que me recomiendes para aprender sobre estos problemas que tuve.

Comment: @PedroÁvila Hola, para colocar el botón donde quieres, pon el código que te comento antes de el título de Proveedor, si te das cuenta en el CodePen que te dejé así viene.

Comment: ya lo solucione modificando el css en el top: -80